# highchart server side drilldown

Tags: highcharts

In this, I need to drilldown via client-side data. How to make drilldown via calling rest API?

Is it possible to via rest API after drilldown we need to drillup for previous data?

http://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/78xsnvw1/

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/`enter code here`

Comment: Hi @mahesh p.v, Could you explain your problem more precisely and provide us with some code that you have tried?

Comment: hi @ppotaczek in high maps i have issue
https://jsfiddle.net/zyoLvu98/

Comment: in above fiddle i have four buttons if we click any button it select that area normal time we hover any state we showing linearGradient color. for selected states iam not getting linearGradient.

Comment: Hi @mahesh p.v, You need to set `color` for select state. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a85hjwmg/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.states.select.color

Comment: thank @ppotaczek but need this way you for selected area.when mouse over on state it changes color

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand. Could you provide me with more detailed description of the problem?